Running into a TypeError with openpyxl Series and unsure why
I am having an issue with using series in openpyxl. This is my code, which takes in a dictionary of dataframes and creates a filtered dataframe based off input parameters. My error occcurs when I try to make a new series, and I get the error message below. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My Reference ranges are correct.
raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'int'>

Here is the code:
def create_chart(workbook, dfs, sheet_name, key, y_label):
    """Generate chart from the dataframe(s)."""

    # create the chart
    chart = openpyxl.chart.ScatterChart()
    chart.title = sheet_name
    chart.x_axis.title = "X values"
    chart.y_axis.title = y_label

    start_row = 1
    start_col = 1
    workbook.save("example.xlsx")

    for material, df in filtered_dfs.items():
        x_values = Reference(ws, min_col=start_col, min_row=start_row+2,
                                      max_row=start_row+1+len(df))
        y_values = Reference(ws, min_col=start_col+1, min_row=start_row + 2,
                                      max_row=start_row + 1 + len(df))
        new_series = series.Series(y_values, x_values)

        workbook.save("example.xlsx")
        start_col += len(df.columns) + 1

    ws.add_chart(chart, "H6")




def write_filtered_dfs_to_excel_sheet(filtered_dfs, ws):
    """Write specified dataframe to column and separate."""

    # write graph to sheet
    start_row = 1
    start_col = 1

    for material, df in filtered_dfs.items():
        # write header for each material
        ws.cell(row=start_row, column=start_col, value=material)

        # write column headers
        for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
            ws.cell(row=start_row + 1, column=start_col + i, value=col)

        # going through each row, column in df and appending to excel
        for row_idx, row in df.iterrows():
            for col_idx, value in enumerate(row):
                ws.cell(row=start_row + 2 + row_idx, column=start_col + col_idx, value=float(value))

        start_col += len(df.columns) + 1

I have error checked it to make sure the ranges and values are correct, and they seem to be. The data is also written correctly in the Excel file before I access it.
Here is an example of the dataframes I would be using.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [0.0000, 3.5714, 7.1429, 10.7143, 14.2857, 17.8571, 21.4286, 25.0000],
    'Y': [0.00000000, 0.14285714, 0.28571429, 0.42857143, 0.57142857, 0.71428571, 0.85714286, 1.00000000]
})


will be hard to tell without an example dataframe.  please provide a minimal reproducible example

how to ask a good question:
how to ask

I don't understand either. I copy the code from OpenPyXL doc: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/scatter.html, I had to change capital "Series" to "series" and use series.Series to create chart, and then I got the same error message as yours.

Please include the complete traceback.

It does appear that the line new_series = series.Series(y_values, x_values) is where the issue is occurring. You want to import "Series' not 'series' from openpyxl.chart and then use the line new_series = Series(y_values, x_values). However you then don't do anything with new_series so the chart wont use it. The code has a unusual flow. There is a lot of unnecessary saving of  the workbook but then after the Chart is added the workbook apparently is not saved. So even if the Chart was created correctly its not going to appear in the Sheet if the workbook is not saved after its added.

@moken Yes, I realised I should have imported Series, not series. (The intelisense on my Clion must be confused, and show some red wavy lines when I import "Series")

3.2.0b1 was released for solely a client who couldn't install checkouts. It works but is not supported in anyway.

Thanks a lot to the comments I believe the mystery is resolved!
The problem is "Series", even though intellisense doesn't like it, we still need to use it (capital S)

import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.chart import (
    ScatterChart,
    Reference,
    Series,
)


def create_chart(workbook, dfs, sheet_name, key, y_label):
    """Generate chart from the dataframe(s)."""

    # create the chart
    chart = openpyxl.chart.ScatterChart()
    chart.title = sheet_name
    chart.x_axis.title = "X values"
    chart.y_axis.title = y_label

    start_row = 1
    start_col = 1

    ws = workbook[sheet_name]

    for material, df in dfs.items():
        x_values = Reference(ws, min_col=start_col, min_row=start_row + 2,
                             max_row=start_row + 1 + len(df))
        y_values = Reference(ws, min_col=start_col + 1, min_row=start_row + 2,
                             max_row=start_row + 1 + len(df))
        new_series = Series(y_values, x_values)
        chart.series.append(new_series)

        start_col += len(df.columns) + 1

    ws.add_chart(chart, "H6")

Confirmed it works:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dfs = {
        "Material": pd.DataFrame({
            'X': [0.0000, 3.5714, 7.1429, 10.7143, 14.2857, 17.8571, 21.4286, 25.0000],
            'Y': [0.00000000, 0.14285714, 0.28571429, 0.42857143, 0.57142857, 0.71428571, 0.85714286, 1.00000000]
        })
    }
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    write_filtered_dfs_to_excel_sheet(dfs, ws)
    create_chart(wb, dfs, wb.sheetnames[0], "Key", "y_label")
    wb.save("example.xlsx")



Look good, but remove both the workbook.save("example.xlsx") lines from the 'create_chart' function and move it to the end of the code (after create_chart(wb, dfs, wb.sheetnames[0], "Key", "y_label") . For this it's only necessary to save the workbook once at the end. That covers both the writing of the Dataframe data and the Chart

@moken, yes, I remove the redundant workbook.save("example.xlsx")

Don't know why your editor doesn't like Series, presumably it's the aliasing. The Series imported from the module is a factory function that creates the right kind of instance of a Series class because the client API is different to the XML implementation.
But why start_row only to overwrite it when creating the references?

Probably lack of docstring: other module: https://imgur.com/a/HRXu8Qp Series:https://imgur.com/a/O0RjdlS

That was the problem. Thank you for helping!

I've made some minor changes for readability because I find functions with long signatures an invitation to disaster in this kind of situation, and avoid your own counters whenever possible. It's why Guido or Raymond or someone invented enumerate().

def create_chart(workbook, dfs, sheet_name, key, y_label):
    """Generate chart from the dataframe(s)."""

    # create the chart
    chart = openpyxl.chart.ScatterChart()
    chart.title = sheet_name
    chart.x_axis.title = "X values"
    chart.y_axis.title = y_label

    x_vals = {"min_col":1, "min_row":3, "max_row":len(df)+2}
    y_vals = {"min_col":2, "min_row":3, "max_row":len(df)+2}


    ws = workbook[sheet_name]

    for material, df in dfs.items():
        x_values = Reference(ws, **x_vals)
        y_values = Reference(ws, **y_vals)
        new_series = Series(y_values, x_values)
        chart.series.append(new_series)

    ws.add_chart(chart, "H6")



I think x_vals and y_vals needs to be inside for material, df in dfs.items(): because min_col needs to be incremented by len(df.columns) + 1. eg. df_1 starts from column1, df_2 starts from column4, df_3 starts from column7..., but agree min_row will always be 3.

Yes, you're almost certainly right: the code probably won't work as it stands. Though I'm not sure that you need to loop over the dataframe at all, probably just the columns as the length will be constant. My main point that building long function calls in a loop can be really difficult to debug and *args and **kw can be really useful in this kind of situation: it's Python, so readability is a design goal.

Yes *args and **kw make Reference easier to read.

IntelliSense just doesn’t like the Series import with a capital S and gives a warning. I tried importing chart.series but that didn’t work. Once I ignored the warning it worked as intended.
